# How to fix the movements of the polygons?

Tags: r, r-sf, gganimate

I want to draw an animated chorophlet map with R and gganimate. I need to show regions changing category, not polygons moving from one place to another.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc <- nc %>% filter(CNTY_ID %in% c(1825:1830))
nc_data <- tribble(~CNTY_ID,~year,~value,
                   1825,2000,1,
                   1825,2001,2,
                   1825,2002,3,
                   1827,2000,3,
                   1827,2001,4,
                   1827,2002,1,
                   1828,2000,2,
                   1828,2001,1,
                   1828,2002,4)
nc <- nc %>% full_join(nc_data,by="CNTY_ID")
nc <- nc %>% mutate(value= as.factor(value) )
p <- nc %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=value), color="black",lwd=.2) +
  transition_time(year)
animate(p,nframe=6)

# same movements with 
p <- nc %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill=value), color="black",lwd=.2) +
  transition_states(year)
animate(p,nframe=27)
```

The expected results would be polygons changing colors... without moving.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I have found the answer :

```
transition_manual(year)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to figure this out for days !!!